# Why does mat-tables matRowDef contain 2 variables?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I just implemented an example mat-table from angular material io. I am going through the template code and I don't understand the need of  **"let row;..."** in the matRowDef in the last line. When removing it, the table runs still fine. Can anyone tell me what is this line for?

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get a whole row value we need it . as you see below i want to get a whole row value on a row click i used let row

```
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
    (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
```

Comment: So, if I want to open a second window for example and display the clicked row's data, it is only possible with that row variable?

Comment: yes. if you want to use that particular row data you must use let row