# What does *matRowDef="let myRowData" do/reference?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material, and the table documentation has the following example snippet:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
```

###### *Source: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#3-define-the-row-templates*

Now I have figured out the `colums: columsToDisplay` part, as far as I understood that assings `columsToDisplay` to the `columns` input of the `MatRowDef` directive (relevant documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatRowDef). And I understand that `let row` creates a reference to *something*, but what? Where would I find the corresponding documentation? And I'm aware that it's the current row (at least that seems obvious to me), I just really need to know how it works, and where this is documented, so I can add it to my own documentation.

I found that post: [Why does mat-tables matRowDef contain 2 variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748312/why-does-mat-tables-matrowdef-contain-2-variables), but it doesn't really answer anything.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The let keyword in Angular declares a template input variable that is referenced within the template. In Angular, the micro syntax is used to configure a directive in a compact and friendly string. It is a capability given in angular to embed the variables in the template directly by translating that string into attributes on the  tag.

Basically it's even more sugar syntax on top of how *ngFor works. I.e `*ngFor == *matRowDef`

This would be the long example

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

where matRowDef would populate a row with data of myRowData.

Some related docs on the subject:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView

Comment: Okay so do I understand correctly that (according to the first link) `let-item` would extract `item` out of a given context? If so, does `let row` just "extract" the whole context? Because I can theoretically name it whatever I please, right? Also, why do I need to provide it  (`let row`)? Just because that's the required semantics? Because technically I don't need it in the `th` definition.

Comment: I sadly don't understand the contents and relevance (to this issue) of the second link, as I'm not really deeply versed in angular.